# Creating a Min Heap of Objects in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, heap

I am trying to create a min heap in Java. I followed the algorithm on this [site](https://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-min-heap/). However, on that site they are passing in integers and i want to pass in objects. My code almost works, but I should be getting this output:

> PARENT : 3 LEFT CHILD : 5 RIGHT CHILD :6
>
> PARENT : 5 LEFT CHILD : 9 RIGHT CHILD :84
>
> PARENT : 6 LEFT CHILD : 19 RIGHT CHILD :17
>
> PARENT: 9 LEFT CHILD:22 RIGHT CHILD:10

But instead i get this:

> PARENT : 6 LEFT CHILD : 9 RIGHT CHILD :9
>
> PARENT : 9 LEFT CHILD : 12 RIGHT CHILD :45
>
> PARENT : 9 LEFT CHILD : 13 RIGHT CHILD :22

So i am missing some numbers and the heap isn't correct. I have looked at everything and it seems like it should be identical in logic. I know the problem is in MiniHeap.java, but i pasted all my code in this project in case that helps.

**MinHeap.java:**

```
package javaapplication2;
public class MinHeap {
    
    private Node[] NHeap;
    private int size;
    private int maxsize;
 
    private static final int FRONT = 1;
 
    public MinHeap(int maxsize)
    {
        this.maxsize = maxsize;
        this.size = 0;
        NHeap = new Node[this.maxsize + 1];
    }
 
    private int parent(int pos)
    {
        return pos / 2;
    }
 
    private int leftChild(int pos)
    {
        return (2 * pos);
    }
 
    private int rightChild(int pos)
    {
        return (2 * pos) + 1;
    }
 
    private boolean isLeaf(int pos)
    {
        if (pos >=  (size / 2)  &&  pos <= size)
        { 
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
 
    private void swap(int fpos, int spos)
    {
        Node tmp;
        tmp = NHeap[fpos];
        NHeap[fpos] = NHeap[spos];
        NHeap[spos] = tmp;
        
 
    }
 
    private void minHeapify(int pos)
    {
        if (!isLeaf(pos))
        { 
            if ( NHeap[pos].getID() > NHeap[leftChild(pos)].getID()  || NHeap[pos].getID() > NHeap[rightChild(pos)].getID())
            {
                if (NHeap[leftChild(pos)].getID() < NHeap[rightChild(pos)].getID())
                {
                    swap(pos, leftChild(pos));
                    minHeapify(leftChild(pos));
                }else
                {
                    swap(pos, rightChild(pos));
                    minHeapify(rightChild(pos));
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
    public void insert(Node element)
    {
        NHeap[++size] = element;
        int current = size;
 
        while (NHeap[current].getID() < NHeap[parent(current)].getID())
        {
            swap(current,parent(current));
            current = parent(current);
        }   
    }
     public void first(Node element)
    {
        NHeap[0] = element; 
    }
    public void print()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= ((size/2)-1); i++ )
        {
            System.out.print(" PARENT : " + NHeap[i].getID() + " LEFT CHILD : " + NHeap[2*i].getID() 
                + " RIGHT CHILD :" + NHeap[2 * i  + 1].getID());
            System.out.println();
        } 
    }
 
    public void minHeap()
    {
        for (int pos = (size / 2); pos >= 1 ; pos--)
        {
            minHeapify(pos);
        }
    }
 
    public int remove()
    {
        int popped = NHeap[FRONT].getID();
        NHeap[FRONT] = NHeap[size--]; 
        minHeapify(FRONT);
        return popped;
    }
}
```

**JavaApplication2.java:**

```
package javaapplication2;
public class JavaApplication2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Node n = new Node();
        n.setID(5);
        Node n1 = new Node();
        n1.setID(45);
        Node n2 = new Node();
        n2.setID(17);
        Node n3 = new Node();
        n3.setID(10);
        Node n4 = new Node();
        n4.setID(84);
        Node n5 = new Node();
        n5.setID(19);
        Node n6 = new Node();
        n6.setID(6);
        Node n7 = new Node();
        n7.setID(22);
        Node n8 = new Node();
        n8.setID(9);
        
       
        System.out.println("The Min Heap is ");
        MinHeap minHeap = new MinHeap(15);
        minHeap.first(n);
        minHeap.insert(n1);
        minHeap.insert(n2);
        minHeap.insert(n3);
        minHeap.insert(n4);
        minHeap.insert(n5);
        minHeap.insert(n6);
        minHeap.insert(n7);
        minHeap.insert(n8);
        
      
        minHeap.print();
//        System.out.println("The Min val is " + minHeap.remove());
    }
    
}
```

**Node.Java:**

```
package javaapplication2;

public class Node {
        public int id;
    public int priority;
    public int timeSlice;
    
    public void setID(int newid){
        id = newid;
    }
    public int getID(){
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a homework question? Have tried with smaller test cases and samples to see if you can pinpoint the error yourself?

Comment: Yes, i had it working correctly with integers. I switched from passing in integers to passing in objects, and the integer for the objects to be sorted by was stored in the object. This should be the same logic, and i cant see how or why its behaving differently. I've been messing with this code all day with no luck.

Comment: `Node` has to implement `Comparable<Node>` and you have to provide the `compareTo()` method.

Comment: I am comparing the integer value of the ID of each node. Where at in the code are you referring to? Shouldn't it be just fine to invoke NHeap.getID() for all comparisons? This program worked when passing integers. I just want objects stored in an object array instead of integers stored in an integer array.

Comment: First, your expected output cannot be created from the input you show in your program. You never create an object with id 3, or 5. Second, the way you find your problem here is by single-stepping in the debugger, or by calling `print` after every insertion. Finally, there's a bug in your `minHeapify` function. For example, if there are only two items in the heap, when you try to add the third you will attempt to compare the root against its non-existent right child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in your `insert` function.

```
public void insert(Node element)
{
    NHeap[++size] = element;
    int current = size;

    while (NHeap[current].getID() < NHeap[parent(current)].getID())
    {
        swap(current,parent(current));
        current = parent(current);
    }   
}
```

Because your first node is at index 1, this can give you an error whenever a node moves up to the root. At that point, `current` will equal 1, and `parent(current)` will return 0. You will then be comparing the root element against whatever random value was at `NHeap[0]`.

You need to make sure that `current` is greater than 1:

```
while (current > 1 && (NHeap[current].getId() < NHeap[parent(current)].getId())
```

There's also an error in your `minHeapify`. You have:

```
private void minHeapify(int pos)
{
    if (!isLeaf(pos))
    { 
        if ( NHeap[pos].getID() > NHeap[leftChild(pos)].getID()  || NHeap[pos].getID() > NHeap[rightChild(pos)].getID())
        {
            if (NHeap[leftChild(pos)].getID() < NHeap[rightChild(pos)].getID())
            {
                swap(pos, leftChild(pos));
                minHeapify(leftChild(pos));
            }else
            {
                swap(pos, rightChild(pos));
                minHeapify(rightChild(pos));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if `NHeap[pos]` has no right child, this will index beyond the valid items in the heap. You will get random stuff in your heap.

The way around this is to determine which of the children is the smallest, taking into account the possibility that there might not be a right child. Then compare the smallest child with the parent:

```
if (isLeaf(pos)) return;

int leftChild = leftChild(pos);
int rightChild = rightChild(pos);

int smallestChild = leftChild;
if (rightChild <= size && NHeap[rightChild] < NHeap[leftChild])
{
    smallestChild = rightChild;
}
if (NHeap[pos] > NHeap[smallestChild])
{
    swap(pos, smallestChild);
    minHeapify(smallestChild);
}
```